# Copy windows shared file from cmd

Tags: windows, network-share, windows-command-prompt

Is there a downloading tool that supports Windows Shared files and works from command line?

Standard copy is getting hanged with no action on my side.
Tried wget but seems it doesn't 'eat' the link.

Comment: Do you mean files that are shared, or files that are accessed from a share?  Can you clarify your question any?

Comment: also see same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10313/79461

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Robocopy is the way to go. Download here:

http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en

/? flag will give you all the options. I've used it for migrating data to new hardware, and it works great.

Edit to add:

Found my ticket with the syntax

robocopy E:\Files F:\Files /e /copyall

/e = copies empty directories
/copyall = copies all NTFS data, attributes, timestamps, ACLs, owner, & auditing info

Comment: And while downloading Robocopy make sure you get the manual as well.

Answer (score 1):

Copy From Shared folder \192.168.14.5\eset_upd

```
net use \\192.168.14.5\eset_upd myPassword /user:myDomain\administrator
copy \\192.168.14.5\eset_upd\*.* c:\eset_upd
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! This is also compatible to Windows Server 2008 R2 Core, where there is only a shell and comes with the OS... But I guess it should read double-backslash before the ip address?

Answer (score 0):

ohhh!! I got a good one for you. It's called TeraCopy! Its fanastic.  By passes the 256 char limit too.

http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php